# Why my websockets application deployed on tomcat is not getting the shibboleth headers?

Tags: apache-2.4, tomcat, mod-proxy, shibboleth, websocket

My stack looks like this:

- Apache httpd server 2.4.12: with mod_shibd, mod_proxy_http & mod_proxy_wstunnel
- Shibboleth 2.5
- Apache Tomcat 7.0.54

Our scenario looks like this:

```
    ---------        --------------        ---------------
    |Browser| <----> |Apache httpd| <----> |Apache Tomcat|
    --------- HTTPS  --------------  HTTP  ---------------
```

The apache httpd configuration:

```
<LocationMatch (^/test-websockets/.*)>
 AuthType Shibboleth
 ShibRequestSetting requireSession true
 ShibUseHeaders On
 ShibExportAssertion Off
 Require valid-user
</LocationMatch>
ProxyPass /test-websockets ws://db-00032:13042/test-websockets
ProxyPassReverse /test-websockets ws://db-00032:13042/test-websockets
```

The apache-tomcat http connector:

```
<Connector port="13042" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="13043" maxHttpHeaderSize="65536"/>
```

And finally the applications(s), any of the websockets samples that comes with the **/examples** applications of the [binary tomcat distribution](https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.54/bin/).

The **good news** are that the websockets application and the shibboleth SP work! So I can play the good and old snake video game being authenticated by our SSO and authorized by my shibboleth SP, hooray!

[image]

**But**, there is always a but, the **bad news** are that if I request the also good and old **/servlets/servlet/RequestHeaderExample** my *shibboleth headers* are not there, **no bueno**!

[image]

Enabling the [Request Dumper Filter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Request_Dumper_Filter) in the application I can see the HTTP request headers that hit the apache-tomcat:

```
===============================================================
 START TIME        =26-Apr-2016 15:59:36
         requestURI=/test-websockets/servlets/images/return.gif
           authType=null
  characterEncoding=null
      contentLength=-1
        contentType=null
        contextPath=/test-websockets
             cookie=_ga=GA1.2.1832568672.1461567525
             cookie=_saml_idp=aHR0cHM6Ly9jZXJuLmNoL2xvZ2lu
             cookie=_shibsession
             header=host=
             header=user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
             header=accept=image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
             header=accept-language=en-US,en;q=0.5
             header=accept-encoding=gzip, deflate
             header=referer=
             header=cookie=
             header=connection=keep-alive
             header=if-modified-since=Fri, 26 Sep 2014 13:25:30 GMT
             header=if-none-match=W/"1231-1411737930000"
             header=cache-control=max-age=0
             locale=en_US
             method=GET
           pathInfo=null
           protocol=HTTP/1.1
        queryString=null
         remoteAddr=128.142.201.245
         remoteHost=128.142.201.245
         remoteUser=null
 requestedSessionId=null
             scheme=http
         serverName=THE ONE DECLARED IN THE APACHE HTTPD VIRTUALHOST SECTION
         serverPort=80
        servletPath=/servlets/images/return.gif
           isSecure=false
 ------------------=--------------------------------------------
 ------------------=--------------------------------------------
           authType=null
        contentType=null
             header=ETag=W/"1231-1411737930000"
         remoteUser=null
             status=304
 END TIME          =26-Apr-2016 15:59:36
 ===============================================================
```

However when I force the browser cache (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>) I get my headers:

[image]

OK, I can see that now in the host header I am getting the apache-tomcat one, however I do not think that it has something to do with the issue, or maybe I am wrong?

Any thoughts on this?

Thanks in advance,

Luis

**PS:** I am wonder if this could be related with the **--enable-proxy_wstunnel=shared** option See ["tunneling secure websocket connections with apache"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468154/tunneling-secure-websocket-connections-with-apache)

Comment: have you filled in the attribute-map.xml? and what is coming in your saml assertion?

Comment: Hello @Rob-d. attribute-map.xml: yes it is filled. saml assertion: once the user authenticates against the IdP this last one responds to my shibboleth SP with the right user data in the assertion, so all good from this side, thanks!

Comment: then, is this not expecting for SSO?, new headers with private browsing session or shib session on the idp expires.

Comment: Hello @Rob-d. mmm, none of them I am afraid. I can see that the session id keeps the same. And in that case I would be redirected to the IdP. Nevertheless I am going to double-check. thanks!